# Relative NSDate with result TheDayBeforeYesterday,Yesterady,Today,Tomorrow

Tags: ios, objective-c, comparison, nsdate, relative-date

I want to check for the date and get the result in 4 Format TheDayBeforeYesterday,Yesterady,Today,Tomorrow.

I have One date and i want to compare that date with the current Date.

Right now i have done this but this is just give me the Day in positive number so i cant get the date is gone or will it still to come that date.

```
-(void)getDateDiffrenceForBirthday:(NSString *)strOriginalDate  

{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *originalDate = [formatter dateFromString:strOriginalDate];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:originalDate
                                                 toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                options:0];

    NSLog(@"Days To Go %d",components.day);

}
```

Comment: unclear, what is endDate in ur code? and what is the solution you want?

Comment: @NAZIK please check it now

Comment: `components.day+1` will solve the problem, I think

Answer (score 2):

You may use this function. It formats argument date as follows:

if date is tomorrow, today, yesterday, day before yesterday, it returns corresponding text

if date is less than a week ago, returns week day, day and month

all other dates formatted in medium style

```
NSString* dateFormatted(NSDate* datetime){
if(datetime==nil){return nil;}

NSDate *todayWithTime=[NSDate date];

NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *todayComponents=[gregorian components: (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate: todayWithTime];
NSDate *tomorrow=[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:86399 sinceDate:[gregorian dateFromComponents: todayComponents]];

NSDateComponents * interval = [gregorian components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit) fromDate:datetime toDate:tomorrow options:0];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:CurrentLocale()];

NSString *result;
if((interval.year==0)&&(interval.month==0)){
    if(interval.day==-1){
        result=NSLocalizedString(@"Tomorrow", @"");
    }else if(interval.day==0){
        result=NSLocalizedString(@"Today", @"");
    }else if(interval.day==1){
        result=NSLocalizedString(@"Yesterday", @"");
    }else if(interval.day==2){
        result=NSLocalizedString(@"The Day Before Yesterday", @"");
    }else if(interval.day<7){
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, d MMMM"];
        result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datetime];
    }else{
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datetime];
    }
}else{
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    result = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datetime];
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code to get the date difference

```
-(void)getDateDiffrenceForBirthday:(NSString *)strOriginalDate  

{
    NSDate *originalDate = [formatter dateFromString:strOriginalDate];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSUInteger unitFlags = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:originalDate toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    NSLog(@"Days To Go %d",[components day]+1);

}
```

[Source](http://cocoamatic.blogspot.in/2010/09/nsdate-number-of-days-between-two-dates.html?showComment=1306198273659#c6501446329564880344).

Comment: you dint get my question... what i want is if my StrOriginalDate is 2013-08-22T00:00:00 then it will give me 126 days.. that is diffrence .. but want to check if that day is gone like 126 days ago.